# net4 Enable/Disable NavigateUrl in Hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

In the **GridView** I have two DropDownList outside in the **GridView**, StartDate and EndDate.

I need enable the **NavigateUrl property** in **HyperLink tag** when in the **DropDownList EndDate** I have selected one value.

The **DropDownList EndDate** is outside in the **GridView**.

My code below but the **NavigateUrl property** in **HyperLink tag** is always enabled in GridView even when in the DropDownList EndDate I don't have selected value...

Why?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
                HyperLink Items = row.FindControl("Items") as HyperLink;

                if (EndDate.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
                {
                    Items.NavigateUrl = ""; 
                }
                else
                {
                    Items.NavigateUrl = string.Format("detail.aspx?di={1}&df={2}", StartDate.SelectedValue, EndDate.SelectedValue));
                }
        }
    }



    protected void EndDate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        GridViewBind();
    }

    protected void StartDate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EndDate.Enabled = true;
        GridViewBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (EndDate.SelectedIndex == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to simply disable the hyperlink by doing 
`Items.Enabled = false;` instead of `Items.NavigateUrl = ""`.